# Adding application section to settings?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

How do you add a section to settings for an application, is it related to NSUserDefaults or is this something completely different? Just not sure what this is called or where to start.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Bundle you add to your app called settings.

Here is the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html

To add a `settings.bundle`, select `New File..` then in the list select `Resource` > `Settings Bundle`. This will add a settings bundle to you project. Which contains some default example settings.

All settings changes made in the settings app are stored in the `NSUserDefaults` so you can easily access them.